# What is the meaning of 'field:'

Tags: c#

Given the following:

```
public enum Test
{
    [field: System.ComponentModel.Description("X")]
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 says it is a keyword (it isn't listed as a keyword though in the Microsoft docs):

[image]

What is 'field:' called and what is it for?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets

Comment: Thank you Amy this is exactly what I was looking for. Searching for these words followed by a colon doesn't search very well, even when surrounding with quotes.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes knowing what to google is a challenge, and putting my cursor on "field" and hitting F1 didn't help.  I didn't know the field target was a thing; I'd only seen this in the context of assembly-level attributes (`[assembly: BlahAttribute`), so on a hunch I googled "c# attribute target".  It's curious they aren't called keywords in the docs.

Comment: Yea I was really just trying to figure out what they were called. The field target is good for applying attributes to auto property backing fields.